# Download file from download link in curl

Tags: curl

Several questions somewhat similar, but don't answer this question.

Attempting to make a cURL request to download from a webpage via a download link:

curl -O https://username:password@app.shiphero.com/dashboard/products# --output doc_test.csv

Unfortunately, this is the link: `https://app.shiphero.com/dashboard/products#` the button gives me when I `copy the link address` in chrome.

As you can see below, there's quite a few buttons on this `products` page:

[image]

All of these links copy to the same address: `https://app.shiphero.com/dashboard/products#`

When you click a link, it immediately downloads the csv file.

Is there a way to make a cURL, or other CLI, request, in order to `Export All Rows`?

I'm aware that the above example is not re-producible. I can't find another site where this occurs. However, it is similar to this site:

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset

Where the desire is to download 1 csv on the page. However, this page gives a direct link to the csv on `copy link address` as follows:

`https://data.ok.gov/sites/default/files/unspsc%20codes_3.csv`

Where as my, unfortunately non reproducible example, does not provide a direct link.

Has anyone come across my initial example in another web page and found a way to handle?

Comment: Your site require a login. Nobody will be able to test if you don't provide credentials

Comment: I can't provide credentials. edited to clarify what I mean.

Comment: You can check what this button does by inspecting it. If it calls data from an API, you may be able to reproduce it with cURL and transfer this data to your file.

Comment: Open dev tools, network tab, then click on the button and check what's happens

Answer (score 0):

Writing from ShipHero. Why not use our API https://developer.shiphero.com/ ?

Comment: The rate limits are terrible